# Access meta reply message

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My backed is giving me some information about the reply in a `meta` field. For example, when going to `#/phoneNumbers/phonelocations/index` a request to `/api/phonelocations` is sent, and this is the data received:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "api_action": "find_all",
        "api_id": "phonelocations",
        "content_type": "application/json",
        "error_code": 200,
        "errors": [
            {
                "admin_message": "",
                "code": 200,
                "message": ""
            }
        ],
        "message": "Successfully read phonelocations",
        "success": true
    },
    "phonelocations": [
        {
            "_id": "0",
            "city": "Berlin",
            "count": 10,
            "country": "DE",
            "country_name": "Germany",
            "loctype": "GEO",
            "loctype_human": "Geographical number",
            "subtype": "49GEO",
            "subtype_human": "German geographical number",
            "type": "phonelocation-faketype"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

This is present in all replies coming from the backend. I would like to use the message in `_reply_meta.message` to display it to the user. Is there a standard way in Ember to access the meta information of the replies?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `store.metadataFor(type)`, in your case:

```
var meta = this.store.metadataFor('phonelocation');
// all metadata is in meta object
meta.message // => "Successfully read phonelocations"
```

See this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/3vfQD/